# Cakephp routing for parameter

Tags: cakephp

I want do routing that "[http://sample.com/sample-A-B-C]".
A=parameter1    B=parameter2   C=parameter3

What should I do?

please tell me the routing setting.

Comment: If this is cakephp2 see here https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action

Comment: I checked.but I don't understand that I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hard to understand what you are trying to do, but I guess you’re looking for something like this.

In your `routes.php`:

```
Router::connect(
    '/sample-:param1-:param2-:param3', // param1 = A, param = B, ...
    array('controller' => 'sample', 'action' => 'view'),
    array(
        // pass the parameters to the Controller function
        'pass' => array('param1', 'param2', 'param3'),
        // optional: only allow a set of characters with regex
        'param1' => '[A-Z]{1}', // only allow one uppercase letter
        'param2' => '[A-Z]{1}',
        'param3' => '[A-Z]{1}'
    )
);
```

In your Controller:

```
class SampleController extends AppController {

    public function view($param1, $param2, $param3) {
        // do stuff here
    }

}
```